# getx: AddController not found. You need to call Get.put(AddController())

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-getx

I am using getx to my project, I am trying to use getx dependency injection. I create AddBinding class:

```
class AddBinding implements Bindings {
  @override
  void dependencies() {
    Get.lazyPut<AddController>(
      () => AddController(
        AddRepository(),
        Get.find<DialogService>(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And In `GetPage` I added this binding like :

```
GetPage(
  name: Routes.ADD,
  page: () => AddPage(),
  binding: AddBinding(),
),
```

Now In my Home page

```
class HomePage extends GetView<HomeController> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // title: const Text('HomePage'),
        title: TabBar(
          controller: controller.controller,
          tabs: controller.myTabs,
        ),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: TabBarView(
          controller: controller.controller,
          physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          children: [
            Container(),
            Container(),
            Container(),
            AddPage(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

I add My AddPage. This is add page:

```
class AddPage extends GetView<AddController> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(child: Container()),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        elevation: 0.0,
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFE57373),
        onPressed: () async {
          controller.showAddDialog();
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),

    );
  }
}
```

But when I clicked on fab `controller.showAddDialog();` I got error:
`E/flutter (26699): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: "AddController" not found. You need to call "Get.put(AddController())" or "Get.lazyPut(()=>AddController())" E/flutter (26699): #0      GetInstance.find package:get/…/src/get_instance.dart:332 E/flutter (26699): #1      Inst.find package:get/…/src/extension_instance.dart:70`

This is AddController:

```
class AddController extends GetxController {
  final AddRepository repository;
  final DialogService dialogService;
  AddController(this.repository, this.dialogService);

  void showAddDialog() {

  }
}
```

What is problem?

This is MaterialApp:

```
GetMaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        initialRoute: Routes.INITIAL,
        theme: appThemeData,
        defaultTransition: Transition.fade,
        initialBinding: MainBinding(),
        locale: const Locale('fa', 'IR'),
        translationsKeys: AppTranslation.translations,
        getPages: AppPages.pages,
      ),
    ),
  );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not navigating to `AddPage` using the GetX navigation system. What you are doing is switching tabs from the same page (HomePage). Therefore the `AddBinding` class has no effects on it. It will only have effect if you were navigating with `Get.toNamed(Routes.ADD)` or `Get.to(()=>AddPage(), binding: AddBinding())`.

One workaround could be put your `AddBinding` dependencies to the tabs parents (HomePage) binding, where you putting your `HomeController`

Comment: In tabview we don't use `Get.to` so haveI just  to put AddController inside mainBinding? This is only solution ?@S. M. JAHANGIR

Comment: Yes! Apparently this is the simplest solution.